# Junit and Spring 5 : All my classes should be multithreading tests expect one class, how can I achieve this? SSL handshake with concurrent

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, email, junit

I'm working on a Spring 5 project and have some very special expectations with junit. Spring 5 now support junit multithreading and that definitely works very well, I'm now running my hundreds of tests into method parrallel multithreading. But I just setup recently my whole automatic mailing system which works like a charm but that's where it start to be problematic : I run a class that send all my mails to test them, and so they are being sent concurently. But as I just tried right now to test it with not only one email at a time but several, I get a strange SSL handshake error which I related to the fact that concurrent mail sending is not supported by most mail clients.

That's where goes my interrogation: how can I run all my test classes with parallel methods execution except for that email batch sending class? 
Maybe I should think about a mail queue to avoid this kind of problem in live? Anyone has an idea?

By the way, in case you wonder I'm yet using gmail client to send mail as I didn't configured it yet for our live mail sending but it will be achieved using dedicated 1and1.fr smtp email client.

Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who feels interested about the solution, here is how I solved it:

I created a new Singleton class which would handle the queue :

```
public class EmailQueueHandler {


/** private Constructor */
private EmailQueueHandler() {}

/** Holder */
private static class EmailQueueHandlerHolder
{
    /** unique instance non preinitialized */
    private final static EmailQueueHandler INSTANCE = new EmailQueueHandler();
}

/** access point for unique instanciation of the singleton **/
public static EmailQueueHandler getInstance()
{
    return EmailQueueHandlerHolder.INSTANCE;
}

private List<EmailPreparator> queue = new ArrayList<>();


public void queue(EmailPreparator email) {
    waitForQueueHandlerToBeAvailable();
    queue.add(email);
}

public List<EmailPreparator> getQueue()
{
    waitForQueueHandlerToBeAvailable();
    List<EmailPreparator> preparators = queue;
    queue = new ArrayList<>();
    return preparators;
}

// This method is used to make this handler thread safe
private synchronized void waitForQueueHandlerToBeAvailable(){}
}
```

I then created a CRON task using @Schedule annotation in my Scheduler bean in which I would correctly handle any mail sending fail.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 30 * SECOND)
public void sendMailsInQueue()
{
    List<EmailPreparator> queue = emailQueueHandler.getQueue();
    int mailsSent = queue.size();
    int mailsFailed = 0;
    for(EmailPreparator preparator : queue)
    {
        try {
            // And finally send the mail
            emailSenderService.sendMail(preparator);
        }
        // If mail sending is not activated, mail sending function will throw an exception,
        // Therefore we have to catch it and only throw it back if the email was really supposed to be sent
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            mailsSent --;
            // If we are not in test Env
            if(!SpringConfiguration.isTestEnv())
            {
                mailsFailed ++;
                preparator.getEmail().setTriggeredExceptionName(e.getMessage()).update();

                // This will log the error into the database and eventually
                // print it to the console if in LOCAL env
                new Error()
                        .setTriggeredException(e)
                        .setErrorMessage(e.getClass().getName());
            }
            else if(SpringConfiguration.SEND_MAIL_ANYWAY_IN_TEST_ENV || preparator.isForceSend())
            {
                mailsFailed ++;
                throw new EmailException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    log.info("CRON Task - " + mailsSent + " were successfuly sent ");
    if(mailsFailed > 0)
        log.warn("CRON Task - But " + mailsFailed + " could not be sent");
}
```

And then I called this mail queue emptyer methods at the end of each unit test in my @After annotated method to make sure it's called before I unit test the mail resulted. This way I'm aware of any mail sending fail even if it appear in PROD env and I'm also aware of any mail content creation failure when testing.

```
@After
 public void downUp() throws Exception
 {
    proceedMailQueueManuallyIfNotAlreadySent();
    logger.debug("After Test");

    RequestHolder requestHolder = securityContextBuilder.getSecurityContextHolder().getRequestHolder();

    // We check mails sending if some were sent
    if(requestHolder.isExtResultsSent())
    {
        for(ExtResults results : requestHolder.getExtResults())
        {
            ExtSenderVerificationResolver resolver =
                    new ExtSenderVerificationResolver(
                            results,
                            notificationParserService
                    );
            resolver.assertExtSending();
        }
  }
  // Some code


}

protected void proceedMailQueueManuallyIfNotAlreadySent()
{
    if(!mailQueueProceeded)
    {
        mailQueueProceeded = true;
        scheduler.sendMailsInQueue();
    }
}
```